# Getting Session ID is Null while Generating Extent Report after Suite Run

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, selenium-extent-report, testng.xml

I have Define , driver.quit in @AfterSuite Annotation. In my TestNG XML , I have configured Extent Report Listener. Now when incase when there is a failure in the Test, the driver shuts down and Report Generation is getting failed with below error 
"[TestNG] Reporter com.ufe.ExtentReportListener.ExtentReportListerner@1832aa failed
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?"

But incase when the Test is passed, Report Gets Generated.

Code:-
public class OrderSubmissionTest extends TestBase{

```
public OrderSubmissionTest(){
    super();
}

@BeforeTest()
public void setup() throws InterruptedException, IOException ,NullPointerException{

    initialization();
    LogInPage=new LogInPage();
}

@Test(priority=1/*dependsOnMethods="CreateCustomerTest"*/)
public void Login_Initiate_Sales() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    searchCustomer=LogInPage.Login(prop.getProperty("Username"), prop.getProperty("Password"));
    salesPage=searchCustomer.InitiateSales();
    createCustomer=salesPage.AddtoBasket();
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] getUFE_Data() throws IOException{
    Object Data[][]=TestUtil.TestData(TestUtil.Sheetname);
    return Data;
}

@Test(priority=2,dataProvider="getUFE_Data",/*retryAnalyzer=com.ufe.util.RetryAnalyzer.class,*/dependsOnMethods="Login_Initiate_Sales")
public void CreateCustomerTest(String Fname, String Lname,String dob,String PIN, String address, String No, String Email) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    createCustomer.CreateContact(Fname, Lname, dob, PIN, address, No, Email);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    salesPage=createCustomer.CreateBillingProfile(Lname, Lname,Fname+Lname, Fname+Lname, Email);    
}   

@Test(priority=3,dependsOnMethods="CreateCustomerTest",enabled=false)
public void AddToBasket() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    salesOfferPage=salesPage.AddAgain();
    System.out.println(salesOfferPage.Write_Select_Offer());
    delivery_page=salesOfferPage.Select_Attribute();
}

@Test(priority=4,dependsOnMethods="AddToBasket",enabled=false)
public void DeliveryScreenTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    delivery_page.validate_delivery_page();
    billingProfileScreen=delivery_page.delivery_type(); 
}

@Test(priority=5,dependsOnMethods="DeliveryScreenTest",enabled=false)
public void BillingProfileValidation() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    billingProfileScreen.validate_Billing_page();
    billingProfileScreen.DisableCreditVetting();
    salesConfirmationScreen=billingProfileScreen.UpdateBillingProfile();
}

@Test(priority=6,dependsOnMethods="BillingProfileValidation",enabled=false)
public void FlowSubmissionTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    orderSubmission=salesConfirmationScreen.validate_Confirmation_page().Proceed_To_NextOrSubmit();
    orderSubmission.ValidateOrderSubmission().Order_Submission();
}

@AfterMethod
public void status(ITestResult result) throws IOException{
    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        TestUtil.TakeScreenShot(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }
}

@AfterSuite()
public void tear_down() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: The issue is with ExtentReportListerner. can you post the code? this error usually happens when you try to take a screenshot or doing something with driver object, but browser session has already closed.

Comment: Yes , you are right . I am trying to attach screenshot in my Extent Report for failure cases due to which this issue is coming. Can you please suggest how this can be fixed ?

Comment: You will have to take the screenshot right away when the test fails and pass only screenshot path to extent report method. It depends on how you implemented the listener.

Comment: Thanks Sureshmani, Let me try this. The same thing happened for WebEventListener. Do you know any way through which we can Generate Report before quitting the driver ? Like here I have defined the listener in TestNG Only .